# Fetching image from database fail after linking storage to public

Tags: laravel

My image is saved to the database correctly, and I can also access the path and image name. I, however, cannot display the image even after writing the correct path in the asset function.
Here is my image store

```
public function storeProductImage(Request $request){

 try{
        
            $request->validate
            ([
                'filename'=>'required',
                'media_type'=>'required',
                'product_id'=>'required',
               
               
            ]);
            if($request->hasfile('filename')){
                $images=$request->file('filename');$name = $request->input('name');


                foreach($images as $image){
                    $name=$image->getClientOriginalName();
                    $path=$image->storeAs('uploads',$name,'public');
                    $mediatype=$request->input('media_type');
                    $productid=$request->input('product_id');
                   
                    ProductMedia::create([
                        'filename'=>$name,
                        'path'=>'/storage/' .$path,
                        'media_type'=>$mediatype,
                        'product_id'=>$productid,
                    ]);
                }
            }
    
          

         return redirect()->route('admin-add-product-route')
            ->with('success-image','Image added successfully');
             
           /*  return back()->with('message', 'Product added successfully'); */
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            return redirect()->route('admin-add-product-route')
            ->with('fail-image','Image Addition failed, fill all fields correctly');

        } 
    }
```

Im trying to get image by id here

```
public function viewAllProducts($id){

        $showProducts=Product::find($id);
        $showOverview=ProductOverview::find($id);
        $showMedia=ProductMedia::find($id);
        $showTechSpecs=ProductTechnicalSpecifications::find($id);
         if (($showProducts === null) || ($showOverview === null) || ($showMedia === null) || ($showTechSpecs === null)){
            
        }
        else{ 

        return view('admin.dashboard.viewAllProductDetails',
        compact('showProducts','showOverview','showMedia','showTechSpecs','id'));
        }}
Then here is my blade.


 <img src="{{asset('/storage/uploads/'.$showMedia->filename)}}" width="500px" height="150vh"alt=""/>
            <h1> {{ $showMedia->filename}}</h1>
    
          
                  <td></td>
                <td>{{ $showProducts->id}}</td>
                <td>{{ $showProducts->name}}</td>
                <td>{{ $showProducts->model}}</td>
                <td>{{ $showProducts->type}}</td>
      
           Kindly help, the image cannon be displayed.
```

Answer (score 1):

When retrieving your models from the database, the code assumes the record for a product has the same id value in all the tables.

I would suggest that the ProductMedia, ProductOverview and ProductTechnicalSpecifications should have a product_id column.

You can then find the records for each product using $showMedia=ProductMedia::whereProductId($id).